# CORS error on production build on device too

Tags: angular, typescript, cors, ionic4

I have built the `Ionic 4` app using this CLI:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

*service.ts*

```
  get(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=52.974431&lon=70.2398363&appid=myapi&units=metric");
  }
```

Why it still give CORS error?

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=52.974431&lon=70.2398363&appid=myid&units=metric'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
>   must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

As per my knowledge, it should run on the device without error no? Why it still shows `http://localhost:8100` on the device? According to [this doc](https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) it should work fine on the device no?

*Note:* I use `chrome://inspect/#devices` to get above error?

Comment: Does your application have an interceptor that is adding the `withCredentials: true` option on all requests?

Comment: @R.Richards I have `AuthGuard` on that page. Why?

Comment: Because the error makes it look like you're passing `withCredentials: true` during the HTTP GET call when it really doesn't need to. An interceptor that adds the option would explain that.

Comment: @R.Richards Good point. But not the issue of mine. I'll put the full answer for this later. Thanks.

Comment: if you got solution of that then please update it because i already got this type of error but now i using HTTP cordova plugin

Comment: @Utpaul You can keep your answer and update it to the `Ionic 4`. I'll accept it.

Comment: @Sampath please check now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently i got same problem but i resolve it by using `cordova-plugin-advanced-http` for android and ios device.

**Install**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm install @ionic-native/http
```

**Use**

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

constructor(private http: HTTP) {}

...

this.http.get('http://ionic.io', {}, {})
  .then(data => {

    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);

  })
  .catch(error => {

    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);

  });
```

More details: see [official link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http)

Comment: Please update this to `Ionic 4` since I use it. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http

Comment: @Sampath now check it